# Summation with group by function in vuejs code

Tags: vuejs2, lodash

I am trying to summation with groupBy and sumBy with lodash on vuejs code. I also try it this link 
https://codepen.io/cmtliton/pen/bjNNNq?editors=1010

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      SaleReports : [
        {
  ProductId: "PVk2WIKjZJ",
  quantity: 2,
  MRP: 15
 },
 {
  ProductId: "PQ_bCOJx5h",
  quantity: 2,
  MRP: 250
 },
 {
  ProductId: "PVk2WIKjZJ",
  quantity: 1,
  MRP: 15
 },
 {
  ProductId: "PQ_bCOJx5h",
  quantity: 1,
  MRP: 250
 }
      ],
      SummationReports : []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getSummationSalesReport () {
      return _(this.SaleReports)
        .groupBy('ProductId')
        .map((g, ProductId) => {
          return {
            ProductId: ProductId,
            quantity: _.sumBy(g, 'quantity'),
            MRP: _.sumBy(g, 'MRP' * 'quantity')
          }
        })
        .values()
        .value()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
  created () {
    this.SummationReports = this.getSummationSalesReport
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{$data | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

I need the result like below:

```
"SummationReports": [
    {
      "ProductId": "PVk2WIKjZJ",
      "quantity": 3,
      "MRP": 750
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "PQ_bCOJx5h",
      "quantity": 3,
      "MRP": 45
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) directly in the view - no need to assign it manually to the data.

In addition, `_.sumBy()` accepts only a single property. Get the `quantity` using `_.sumBy()`, and for the `MRP`, get the 1st item `MRP` and multiply it with the `quantity` sum.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      SaleReports: [{"ProductId":"PVk2WIKjZJ","quantity":2,"MRP":15},{"ProductId":"PQ_bCOJx5h","quantity":2,"MRP":250},{"ProductId":"PVk2WIKjZJ","quantity":1,"MRP":15},{"ProductId":"PQ_bCOJx5h","quantity":1,"MRP":250}],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    SummationReports() {
      return _(this.SaleReports)
        .groupBy('ProductId')
        .map((g, ProductId) => {
          const quantity = _.sumBy(g, 'quantity')
          
          return ({
            ProductId: ProductId,
            quantity,
            MRP: quantity * _.get(g, '[0].MRP'),
          })
        })
        .values()
        .value()
    }
  },
})
```

```css
/** hide the annoying vue dev mode messages **/
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ SummationReports }}</pre>
</div>
```